# Include js for conditional statements in Wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I have to include  a stylesheet and js in wordpress plugin which I am developing by keeping in mind the Wordpress plugin standards. 
How do I add this line of code to the front end which will be dependent on the browser type. 
For other styles I included, I have made use of wp_register_style and wp_enqueue_style functions. 
But in  this particular case I have doubts.

```
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>   
  <link href="<?php echo plugins_url('/plugin_name/js/htmlxx.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

 <![endif]-->
```

Can anyone provide me some suggestion on this.

---

Update--

I would like to know how to add conditional statement for javascript in wordpress plugin

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
function your_plugin_register_scripts() {
  global $wp_styles; // use global $wp_styles to add conditional wrapper.
  if (!is_admin()) {
    wp_register_style( 'main-style', '/path/to/your/css/style.css', array(), '', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main-style' );
    $wp_styles->add_data( 'main-style', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );

  }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_plugin_register_scripts' );
```

Comment: How to use this in case of scripts?

Comment: @user3230561 Which script?

Comment: I mean if I have to load javascript files in lt IE 9 condition then what am I suppose to do?

Comment: @user3230561 same. Just replace wp_register_style() with wp_register_script(). The $wp_styles->add_data() method adds conditional wrapper so it won't matter whether you use scripts or styles

Comment: I followed the step but.. I can see the script getting added also in firefox browser which shouldn't have happened right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52190/discussion-between-user3230561-and-jay-bhatt)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52231/discussion-between-jay-bhatt-and-user3230561)